# Format the color of a cell in a pandas dataframe according to text of the other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, styling

Here is my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A001','B001'],'201901_TL': ['GREEN','RED'],'201901_Score':[90.87,59.32],'201902_TL':['GREEN','YELLOW'],'201902_Score':[99.87,89.32]})
```

Column `201901_TL` is the color for the value in column `201901_Score`, and also `201902_TL` is the color for `201902_Score`.

That means if `'201901_TL'= 'GREEN'`, value 90.87 in column `201901_Score` should be highlighted as Green.

I have made multiple attempts, but all failed. please help me, thanks!

Comment: Just to be more clear, are you asking about highlighting cells in an excel sheet output ? Normally dataframes are just a data format which don't really use colors. Or are you talking about `Styling` dataframes which is still under development ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use styling function to highlight cells. and output it as an excel sheet.